# Python remove element from array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I have to create a python Brute-force for a school project.
I have a shadow file and i have to brute force passwords.

On the list I have few passwords I don't need, so I want to remove them from my array.
So I have an array with all my passwords. I've wrote a if condition to check if password is different than "*" or "!".

```
for mdp in passwd:
    if mdp != '*' or mdp != '!':
        str(mdp)
        list.append(mdp)
        print(list)
```

But when I print my array password with "!" and "*" are still inside... I don't know why.

Comment: `or` should have been an `and`. Think about it and see if you can work out why.

Comment: try to redo your if into: `if mdp not in ['*',  '!']:`

Comment: thanx for answer @ParitoshSingh 
But i don"t understand why to use and... I'll check it online. THanx again

Comment: "or" condition is correct. I guess you should be checking for containment as mentioned in the answer below

Comment: @KannappanSirchabesan No it isnt. To the OP: `mdp != '*'` or `mdp != '!'`. Assume you encounter a `*` symbol. what happens to the conditional? It evalutes to `False or True` and becomes True, and the if block still executes. You need to ensure mdp is neither `*` nor `!`. That is, the condition should fail if "any one" of the 2 negation matches give a False. (The Not changes conditionals in strange ways, and it helps to think of it using pen and paper and actually working it out.)

Comment: Tl;DR With the `or` present, that if block will always execute because 1 character cannot match both `*` and `!` at the same time, leading to atmost one False in the evaluation.

Comment: ok makes sense. I still think Austin's answer is the correct one as passwords are not going to be 1 character long.

Comment: I think you need to post some fuller, working code. What you've posted here looks like just a small part of what you're running. For example, I assume passwd is a list, but that's unclear. You're printing "list" every time you go around your for loop...why? You're convering mpd to a string, but discarding that result. Why? Other comments have probably answered your question for you (the use of != and OR mean you'll always evaluate to True in that condition) but it would have helped to see more of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a containment check, not `!=` check. Do a list-comprehension:

```
password = ['ahdjd', 'xj*', '!jr']

new_password_list = [x for x in password if '*' not in x and '!' not in x]
print(new_password_list)
# ['ahdjd']
```

Answer (score 0):

the major issue with your code is the `or` in your if statement.
think of the following, assume your password is '!' not you get into your if, it check if the password is not '*' see that that is correct and goes inside, this is bad. the same issue works if your password was '*', it will check if its '*' see that it is and will then will engage the `or` and check if its '!' see that it isnt and goes inside the if, this is still wrong.
what you want to do here is have an `and` so your password must be *both* not '*' and not '!'
also, you can use fancier coding styles like comprehensions and member testing
also, do not use the word `list` as a variable, because it will shadow the type list
and together you will get:
`filtered = [item for item in passwd if item not in ['*', '!']]`
this assumes that the passwords you want to filter out are a single character long